# acceder a un campo de un array de arrays en php

Tags: php, array, prestashop

queria acceder a un campo de un array de arrays (no se si sera un archivo json). El campo al que quiero acceder es el `[id_product] => 42` que esta en el array `[_products:protected]` y que a su vez esta en el array `[cart]`. Todo esto es lo que arroja un `print_r` de un array. Y este es el contenido de ese array (lo que busco esta casi arriba de todo lo comento para que no os perdais en el array ya que es bastante extenso):

```
Array
(
    [id_order] => 47
    [cookie] => Cookie Object
        (
            [_content:protected] => Array
                (
                    [date_add] => 2021-10-09 17:05:41
                    [id_lang] => 2
                    [id_currency] => 2
                )

            [_name:protected] => PrestaShop-c25090d26f43855ffe0e8f44754db695
            [_expire:protected] => 1635527141
            [_domain:protected] => xn--tiendadesueos-skb.com
            [_path:protected] => /
            [cipherTool:protected] => PhpEncryption Object
                (
                )

            [_modified:protected] => 1
            [_allow_writing:protected] => 1
            [_salt:protected] => eCOGVYqg
            [_standalone:protected] => 
            [_secure:protected] => 1
        )

    [cart] => Cart Object
        (
            [id] => 56
            [id_shop_group] => 1
            [id_shop] => 1
            [id_address_delivery] => 7
            [id_address_invoice] => 7
            [id_currency] => 2
            [id_customer] => 4
            [id_guest] => 107
            [id_lang] => 2
            [recyclable] => 0
            [gift] => 0
            [gift_message] => 
            [mobile_theme] => 0
            [date_add] => 2021-10-09 17:05:00
            [secure_key] => 3fde1aab9e1e1a2c7459631509b32bb0
            [id_carrier] => 8
            [date_upd] => 2021-10-09 17:05:09
            [checkedTos] => 
            [pictures] => 
            [textFields] => 
            [delivery_option] => {"7":"8,"}
            [allow_seperated_package] => 0
            [_products:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id_product_attribute] => 0
                            [id_product] => 42
                            [cart_quantity] => 1
                            [id_shop] => 1
                            [id_customization] => 
                            [name] => Motosierra
                            [is_virtual] => 0
                            [description_short] => 
                            [available_now] => 
                            [available_later] => 
                            [id_category_default] => 2
                            [id_supplier] => 0
                            [id_manufacturer] => 0
                            [manufacturer_name] => 
                            [on_sale] => 0
                            [ecotax] => 0.000000
                            [additional_shipping_cost] => 0.000000
                            [available_for_order] => 1
                            [show_price] => 1
                            [price] => 1.1
                            [active] => 1
                            [unity] => 
                            [unit_price_ratio] => 0.000000
                            [quantity_available] => 645
                            [width] => 0.000000
                            [height] => 0.000000
                            [depth] => 0.000000
                            [out_of_stock] => 2
                            [weight] => 0
                            [available_date] => 0000-00-00
                            [date_add] => 2021-09-22 21:38:06
                            [date_upd] => 2021-10-09 16:55:00
                            [quantity] => 1
                            [link_rewrite] => motosierra
                            [category] => inicio
                            [unique_id] => 0000000042000000000070
                            [id_address_delivery] => 7
                            [advanced_stock_management] => 0
                            [supplier_reference] => 
                            [customization_quantity] => 
                            [price_attribute] => 
                            [ecotax_attr] => 
                            [reference] => mtsrra
                            [weight_attribute] => 
                            [ean13] => 
                            [isbn] => 
                            [upc] => 
                            [mpn] => 
                            [minimal_quantity] => 1
                            [wholesale_price] => 0.000000
                            [id_image] => 42-151
                            [legend] => 
                            [reduction_type] => 0
                            [is_gift] => 
                            [reduction] => 0
                            [reduction_without_tax] => 0
                            [price_without_reduction] => 1.1
                            [specific_prices] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [stock_quantity] => 645
                            [price_without_reduction_without_tax] => 1.1
                            [price_with_reduction] => 1.1
                            [price_with_reduction_without_tax] => 1.1
                            [total] => 1.1
                            [total_wt] => 1.1
                            [price_wt] => 1.1
                            [reduction_applies] => 
                            [quantity_discount_applies] => 
                            [allow_oosp] => 0
                            [features] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [rate] => 0
                            [tax_name] => 
                        )

                )

            [_taxCalculationMethod:protected] => 1
            [webserviceParameters:protected] => Array
                (
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [id_address_delivery] => Array
                                (
                                    [xlink_resource] => addresses
                                )

                            [id_address_invoice] => Array
                                (
                                    [xlink_resource] => addresses
                                )

                            [id_currency] => Array
                                (
                                    [xlink_resource] => currencies
                                )

                            [id_customer] => Array
                                (
                                    [xlink_resource] => customers
                                )

                            [id_guest] => Array
                                (
                                    [xlink_resource] => guests
                                )

                            [id_lang] => Array
                                (
                                    [xlink_resource] => languages
                                )

                        )

                    [associations] => Array
                        (
                            [cart_rows] => Array
                                (
                                    [resource] => cart_row
                                    [virtual_entity] => 1
                                    [fields] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id_product] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [required] => 1
                                                    [xlink_resource] => products
                                                )

                                            [id_product_attribute] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [required] => 1
                                                    [xlink_resource] => combinations
                                                )

                                            [id_address_delivery] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [required] => 1
                                                    [xlink_resource] => addresses
                                                )

                                            [id_customization] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [required] => 
                                                    [xlink_resource] => customizations
                                                )

                                            [quantity] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [required] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [configuration:protected] => PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Configuration Object
                (
                    [shop:PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Configuration:private] => 
                    [parameters:protected] => 
                )

            [addressFactory:protected] => PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\AddressFactory Object
                (
                )

            [shouldSplitGiftProductsQuantity:protected] => 
            [shouldExcludeGiftsDiscount:protected] => 
            [id_shop_list] => Array
                (
                )

            [get_shop_from_context:protected] => 1
            [table:protected] => cart
            [identifier:protected] => id_cart
            [fieldsRequired:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => id_currency
                    [1] => id_lang
                )

            [fieldsSize:protected] => Array
                (
                    [secure_key] => 32
                )

            [fieldsValidate:protected] => Array
                (
                    [id_shop_group] => isUnsignedId
                    [id_shop] => isUnsignedId
                    [id_address_delivery] => isUnsignedId
                    [id_address_invoice] => isUnsignedId
                    [id_carrier] => isUnsignedId
                    [id_currency] => isUnsignedId
                    [id_customer] => isUnsignedId
                    [id_guest] => isUnsignedId
                    [id_lang] => isUnsignedId
                    [recyclable] => isBool
                    [gift] => isBool
                    [gift_message] => isMessage
                    [mobile_theme] => isBool
                    [allow_seperated_package] => isBool
                    [date_add] => isDate
                    [date_upd] => isDate
                )

            [fieldsRequiredLang:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [fieldsSizeLang:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [fieldsValidateLang:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [tables:protected] => Array
                (
                )

            [image_dir:protected] => 
            [image_format:protected] => jpg
            [translator:protected] => 
            [def:protected] => Array
                (
                    [table] => cart
                    [primary] => id_cart
                    [fields] => Array
                        (
                            [id_shop_group] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 1
                                    [validate] => isUnsignedId
                                )

                            [id_shop] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 1
                                    [validate] => isUnsignedId
                                )

                            [id_address_delivery] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 1
                                    [validate] => isUnsignedId
                                )

                            [id_address_invoice] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 1
                                    [validate] => isUnsignedId
                                )

                            [id_carrier] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 1
                                    [validate] => isUnsignedId
                                )

                            [id_currency] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 1
                                    [validate] => isUnsignedId
                                    [required] => 1
                                )

                            [id_customer] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 1
                                    [validate] => isUnsignedId
                                )

                            [id_guest] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 1
                                    [validate] => isUnsignedId
                                )

                            [id_lang] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 1
                                    [validate] => isUnsignedId
                                    [required] => 1
                                )

                            [recyclable] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 2
                                    [validate] => isBool
                                )

                            [gift] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 2
                                    [validate] => isBool
                                )

                            [gift_message] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 3
                                    [validate] => isMessage
                                )

                            [mobile_theme] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 2
                                    [validate] => isBool
                                )

                            [delivery_option] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 3
                                )

                            [secure_key] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 3
                                    [size] => 32
                                )

                            [allow_seperated_package] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 2
                                    [validate] => isBool
                                )

                            [date_add] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 5
                                    [validate] => isDate
                                )

                            [date_upd] => Array
                                (
                                    [type] => 5
                                    [validate] => isDate
                                )

                        )

                    [classname] => Cart
                )

            [update_fields:protected] => 
            [force_id] => 
        )

    [altern] => 1
)
```

---

efectivamente es una clase. Se trata del parametro `$params` de un hook de prestashop. Y se accede asi:

```
$products = $params['cart']->getProducts(true);
foreach ($products as $product) 
        {
            $id_product = $product['id_product'];
            $cantidad = $product['cart_quantity'];
            $referencia = $product['reference'];
            mail("miCorreo@gmail.com", "yay", $id_product.$referencia.$cantidad);
    }
```

mando los parametros por email ya que no hay manera de visualizarlos en prestashop ya que es un hook que se desencadena cuando se paga un producto.

Comment: Esto parece ser una clase o algún tipo de objeto... Mi pregunta es, ¿esa clase u objeto no tiene métodos para acceder a sus propiedades? Si la propiedad es `private` o `protected` es posible que no puedas acceder a ella directamente, sino a través de un método. Creo que falta contexto en tu pregunta, pues tiene pinta de tener que acceder por medio del objeto. Sería algo como `$cart->getProducts()[0]->getId()` por poner un ejemplo, donde `$cart` sería una instancia `Cart Object`  y si ese objeto está anidado en otro objeto, obtendrás `$cart` con el método destinado a ello en ese otro objeto.

Answer (score 1):

te has respondido tú mismo, pero lo hago yo aquí para dejarlo bien claro. Lo que pasa es que cart no es un array sino un objeto de la clase Cart de PrestaShop.

Osea, el parámetro $params que recibe el hook que estás tratando es un array que contiene un elemento bajo el índice 'cart', que es un objeto Cart, representando el carrito actual del comprador.

Quieres acceder a lo que crees es un sub array de Cart, '_products', que efectivamente es un array, pero dentro del objeto es una propiedad protected, por lo que no puedes acceder a ella directamente.

Sin embargo, como comenta A. Cedano, existe un método en la clase Cart para poder obtener el contenido de esa propiedad, en este caso getProducts().

```
$products = $params['cart']->getProducts(true);
```

Y ya tienes los productos para hacer con ellos lo que quieras, en tu caso enviar un email.